# How to reliably synchronize data across microservices

Tags: caching, apache-kafka, microservices

I'm building a system composed of microservices, where some microservices need to 'cache' data owned by some other microservice - this is a classic data denormalization scheme.

The microservice which owns the data publishes state change events to a Kafka topic, so that other microservices can consume to keep their cache up-to-date. However, there are several challenges with such an approach, for example: the data in the Kafka topic is kept for a limited period of time (7 days), and a new consuming microservice deployed weeks later still needs a way to build its cache from scratch.

I've looked at different approaches to tackle this problem, including using the Transactional Outbox pattern and/or Kafka Connect, but could not find a comprehensive enough solution - one that performs sync checksum checks and can self-heal in case a cache goes out of sync.

Can anyone recommend a pattern or technology that adequately solves this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Keep data you want to cache in a compacted topic. As [Log Compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) described in Kafka documentation, you can keep the most updated value for a key in the topic and update your microservice's cache with those values.

> Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last
> known value for each message key within the log of data for a single
> topic partition. It addresses use cases and scenarios such as
> restoring state after application crashes or system failure, or
> reloading caches after application restarts during operational
> maintenance

Comment: Thanks, log compaction seems to be an interesting and relevant capability. Unfortunately, I cannot use it in my system because the message key I'm using is different than the DB entity key (the reasoning behind it is quite complex. and involves scale, partitioning and ordering). In fact, I'm using a coarse-grain message key, which means that if I use log compaction, I expect many of the DB entity state change messages would not be retained.